# changing style of the row in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

Hi
I am developing a project n Zend framework. Here in a form when a user select "Other state" Value, I want to display a row. But I don't know how it is?
id of the select dropdown is state and the id of the other state text box is other_state. 
Below is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#state").change(function() {
$("#other_state").parent().css({"display":"block"});


});});
```

My problem is that this code only displays the text box, not displays the label for that text box

below is the code for that other state row

```
'other_state' => array('text', array(
            'required' => true,
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            'decorators' => $elementDecorators,
            'label' => 'Other State:',
            'class' => 'other_state', 
        ))
```

Also i have set the style see below

```
.other_state{
display:none;
```

}

Please help me

I want to display " Other state : Text box here"  when a user select Other From the state dropdown . Here other state is with in one `<td>` and the text box with in the next `<td>` of the same row

Comment: You'll need to show the HTML, else how would we know the structure of DOM to write down the solutioen

Comment: atleast show the html of other state entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery selector should match your CSS selector. If items of class "other_state" are hidden, to show all items of class "other_state" you should use the following:

```
$(".other_state").show();
```

From what little I can see of your markup, it's not that element's parent that is being hidden by your CSS.

See [the jQuery class selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) for additional information.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should use class as selector because you have used `class = other state` in your other state array...

```
$(".other_state").parent().css({"display":"block"});
```

and i am not getting why you are using parent()..try this one also...

```
$(".other_state").css({"display":"block"});
```